# Memcached Client-Server communication

Tags: memcached, spymemcached

I've been researching memcached, and I'm planning on using that with spymemcached on the client. I'm just curious how client/server communication works between the two.  When creating a memcached client object, you can pass in a list of servers, but after the client is created is there any communication between the servers and the client saying that they are still alive and that the client send that particular server information? I've tried looking through the memcached and spymemcached documentation sites, but haven't found anything yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spymemcached does not send any special messages to make sure that the connection is still alive, but you can do this in your application code if necessary by sending no-op messages to each server. You should also note that the TCP layer employs mechanisms such as keep-alive and timeout in order to try to detect dead connections. These parameters however may be different depending on the operating system you are using.